# PHP stripping out specific text from string

Tags: php, regex

I think I'm going about this the wrong way, but here's what I'm doing.

I have a string passed to me from my PBX, which I'm attempting to grab only the phone number,
and even the text inside the double quotes, if they exist.

```
<?php
  $string = '"John Smith" <sip:15558740205@pbx.domain.co:5060;user=phone>';
?>
```

I'm positive using a form of regex will be better to grab the number and name in separate variables, but since I'm not too good at regex yet, I'm resorting to `explode()`

I'm not doing too well with it, and it's getting messing with exploding the string at the `@` sign, then at the `:`.  This leaves the name.

How would I strip out the number after the `<sip:` before the `@`?

Comment: is double-quoted part optional, or does format always stay the same? I mean, immediate solution will be something like `/"([^"])+"\D+(\d+)/`. This regex can (and should) be improved (adding `<sip:(\d+)@` part check  instead of simple `(\d+)`, for example) if the strings you're working with can be of different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you may want to do is to split (using regexp) into part before and after `<sip:`

```
^(.*?)\s*<sip\:(.+)>\s*$
```

`\s*` means to skip any white spaces if there are any.

Matching phone number is:`\d+` or `[0-9]{1,}` or whichever combo you like.

Matching the contents of `""` would be trivial if you can rely that they are always there: `\s*"([^"]+)"\s*` or little worse if they are just optional: `\s*(?:"([^"]+)"\s*)?`

So lets put it all together:

```
$regex = '~^\s*(?:"([^"]+)"\s*)?<sip:(\d+)@.+>\s*~i';
$matches = array();
if( preg_match($regex, $string, $matches)){
    list(, $name, $phone) = $matches;
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining how the regex works.  (I'm assuming `(.?*)` was a typo and you really meant `(.*?)`).  Also, `<`, `:` and `@` have no special meaning, so you don't have to escape them.  That's especially important in the case of the angle brackets because some regex flavors use `\<` and `\>` as word boundaries.

Comment: @AlanMoore thanks for notes. `(.?*)` was indeed a typo and I've removed obsolete escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with regexp:

```
preg_match('/(?:"([^"]*)")?\s*<.*sip:(\d+\)/', $string, $match);
$name = $match[1];
$phone = $match[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<sip:([0-9]{1,})@
```

is the regex you need

```
preg_match('/".*?" <sip:([0-9]+)@/', $string, $matches); 
//matches[1] contains the name
//matches[2] contains the number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:\"([^\"]+)\" )?\<sip\:(\d+)\@/i', $string, $matches))
    list(, $name, $phone) = $matches;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
check this

<?php

  $string = '"John Smith" <sip:15558740205@pbx.domain.co:5060;user=phone>';

  $first = explode("<sip:", $string);

  $second =  explode("@", $first[1]);

  echo $second[0];
?>
```